# Partial fractions where the denominator is one function

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, partial-fractions

I need to solve this differential equation for x:

$$ \frac{dv}{dx} = \frac{4000}{v} - 0.9v $$

Rearranging:

$$ \frac{dx}{dv} = \frac{1}{4000v^{-1} - 0.9v} $$

How would I go about splitting this into partial fractions so that I could integrate it?

Comment: The numbers even work out nicely, because $\frac{v}{4000-0.9v^2}=\frac{10v}{40000-9v^2}$, and now the bottom factors as $(200-3v)(200+3v)$.  Thank you, problem setter!  Now we use partial fractions.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, using $v^{-1}$, though perfectly correct, made things more difficult-looking.

Comment: Apologies, I screwed up. (Need coffee). Partial fractions are unnecessary, just make the substitution $u=4000-0.9v^2$.  Partial fractions do work, but are unnecessary.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I did end up using u-substitution. I wanted to use partial fractions because that was how Wolfram did it (didn't show the method though). This was much easier, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you need to consider the ODE as:

$$\frac{dv}{dx}=\frac{a}{v}-bv=\frac{a-bv^2}{v}$$ and so if $v\neq 0$ then you get: $$\frac{v}{a-bv^2}dv=dx$$

Comment: And how would I simplify this? Neither 4000 nor 0.9 are perfect squares.

Comment: @YoussefSami: You are solving this ODE. It is separable so you need just taking integrals from both sides. You don't need to make the numbers squared.

Comment: What I mean is, how would I integrate $ \frac{v}{a-bv^2}dv $ ?

Comment: Partial fractions as shown by  André Nicolas

Comment: $$\int\frac{v}{a-bv^2}dv=-\frac{1}{2b}\ln|a-bv^2|+c$$

Comment: @Superabound: Of course, he could take $a-bv^2=u$ as a very simple substitution. Thanks.

Comment: I did end up using u-substitution. I wanted to use partial fractions because that was how Wolfram did it (didn't show the method though). This was much easier, thank you!

Comment: @YoussefSami: Y're welcome. :)